# confusion matrix of data set with probability showing error

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I was trying to generate a confusion matrix with data set with two columns 
Class of data type `"factor"` (levels: owner and nonowner) and Probability of data type `"numeric"`

```
Summary(owner.df)
      Class     Probability    
 nonowner:12   Min.   :0.0031  
 owner   :12   1st Qu.:0.1240  
               Median :0.5639  
               Mean   :0.5039  
               3rd Qu.:0.8580  
               Max.   :0.9959 

sapply(owner.df, class)
      Class Probability 
   "factor"   "numeric"
```

following is the code:

```
confusionMatrix(ifelse(owner.df$Probability>0.5, 'owner', 'nonowner'), owner.df$Class)
```

but it's throwing an

> Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.

I tried changing the data `type of` Class column 
it is not helping

Comment: Please share the code for producing the dataframes.

Comment: I don't think you understand confusion matrices. They are constructed from a cross-tabulation of two variable that have the same set of levels (as the error message clearly states). You might have had such a pair of variables at some point but perhaps you have done some summarizing operation on them?